# How to line 3 div's in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage to get cover photos from eBooks next to each other. Under each photo there are two buttons. see picture.
I used one div as a container, then I used `<li>` because I will have a lot more books. This page is on a fluid website.

```
<div id="ebooks_container">

<li> 
  <div id="ebook_single"><img src="cover1.jpg">
  <div id="download_btn">         
  <a href="eBooks_ENG/eBook1.epub">DOWNLOAD</a>
</div>
    <div id="review_btn"><a class="inline" href="#data2">REVIEW</a>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I can't get the buttons under the image and when I copy this code and paste it under this the next eBook single div shows up under the first.
I want them next to each other.

Hope someone can help me. I know a little bit of CSS3 but I'm an amateur :)

This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: review button is appearing to next row and you need that next to download in same row is it ?

Comment: For validation: Wrap the list items inside `<ul>` not inside a `<div>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uajrr34p/

try this if you need modification tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just starting out. I would try to find an online video resource to help you learn like lynda or treehouse. (am i allowed to plug these website names? I am not sponsored by either).

I have a rough layout of what you are looking for. This might help.

UPDATE: The reason this code is effecting your current code is because these styles are being applied to ALL of your 'UL', 'LI' tags. You need to make this 'UL' unique by adding a class to it. I update the code to show you want I mean.

HTML

```
<ul class="book_covers clearfix">

    <li>
        <div>Image Panel</div>
        <a class="btn1" href="#">Button1</a>
        <a class="btn2" href="#">Button2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Image Panel</div>
        <a class="btn1" href="#">Button 1</a>
        <a class="btn2" href="#">Button2</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
.book_covers { 
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.book_covers li {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
.book_covers li div{
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 5%;
    background: blue;
    border:2px solid #000;

}
.book_covers li .btn1,
ul li .btn2{
    width: 42.5%;
    height: 22.5%;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.book_covers li .btn1{
    margin:0 2.5% 5% 5%;
    background: orange;
}
.book_covers li .btn2{
    margin:0 5% 5% 2.5%;
    background: pink;
}
```

[Here is the updated fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/h5ehzx9u/1/)

Comment: It looks like this is what I need. Thanks. I will try this and tweek. Let you know.

Comment: It's starting to look good. There is only one problem, The ul and li are interfering with my nav bar. My website is [link] (http://www.bibleopen.org)  The new page is not there yet. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Here is the CSS for the Navbar: /*Begin logo and nav*/
.logo {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 max-width: 198px;
 max-height: 73px;
}
.nav {
 margin-left: 2%;
 /*text-align: left;*/
 font-size: 0.8em;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav ul{
 margin-top: 11px; 
}
.nav li {
 margin-top: 4px; 
}
.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 background-color: #DDDDDD;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
}
.nav a:hover {
 color: #E78500;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav a.thispage {
 background-color: #E78500;
 color: #fff;
}

Comment: Could you upload your code on your website so I can see what you are having trouble with :)

Answer (score 0):

not tested but should work

```
<style>
ul{
   list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
    border:5px solid #ccc;
    background:#ccc;
    width:260px;
    height:400px;
    margin-right:4px;
    float:left;
}
li div{
  width: 100%;
  height:90%;
  background:#dedede;
}
li span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 5%;
  background:#fff;
  padding:8px;
    border:5px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li>
        <div>image</div>
        <span>Download</span>
        <span>Review</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>image</div>
        <span>Download</span>
        <span>Review</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might look something like:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/javascript'>
      @import main.css;
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='cnt1'>
    <img id='img1' src='cover1.jpg' />
    <a href='eBooks_ENG/eBook1.epub' class='btns' id='dwn'>DOWNLOAD</a>
    <a href='#data2' class='btns' id='rev'>REVIEW</a>
  </div>
  <div name='data2' id='data2'>Your data here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css** may look something like:

```
#cnt1{
  height:320px; width:300px; position:relative;
}
#img1{
  display:block; height:300px; width:300px;
}
.btns{
   display:block; height:20px; width:150px; text-align:center; float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@magnetwd
Thanks for looking into my problem.
I uploaded a duplicate site, this is the page [link] (http://hoddenbagh.nl/test_bibleopen/subjects_eBooks.html)
The NAV bar is not good anymore.
And the shadow Gif under the photo neither.
Probably that all has to do with the new CSS.

To compare, this is the original site. NAV bar and photo shadow are good. [link] (http://hoddenbagh.nl/bibleopen/index.html)

P.S. I didn't do much on styling yet and the buttons are still basic.

Comment: I update my response with the fixed code. If it helped, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You've been a great help. Thanks. This was the solution!
I only don't understand why the shadow under the photo (under the NAV bar) is not transparant and on the the right place, I didn't change the code for that.

Comment: And maybe... you want to tell me how I can add the following code to btn2: <a class="inline" href="#data2"> Or do I have to ask this question somewhere else?